# NetSuite: getListAsync() how do you get the jobId?

Tags: netsuite

The getListAsync() is void and you can pass in BaseRef array or BaseRef array plus an object for userState. What is the object that you use for the userState? I'm trying to get Employees record.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at "Responsive Windows Clients" part on page number 1181.
Here is the [link](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=-K8SBW_WRpUC&pg=PA1182&lpg=PA1182&dq=What%20is%20the%20object%20that%20you%20use%20for%20the%20userState?%20%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=hwk8h7bTgf&sig=ACfU3U121Cy3iTOKOj5lSH2RLjoE2KWkZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY2dfEqsHmAhXosIsKHYXQBVMQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=What%20is%20the%20object%20that%20you%20use%20for%20the%20userState%3F%20%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5&f=false) to the book.